Unknown underwater acoustic sound source
I often have to deal with spectrograms similar to the one below, I have some ideas as to what the different signatures might come from but I still have some doubts. Do you have any idea as to what that might be.
I suspect the low frequency (100Hz) signal to be hydrophone noise, but the higher frequency signal seems to high to be blue whales.
Some context: This spectrogram is from a tagged elephant seal out at sea in the southern Indian Ocean. He is drifting passively (ie sleeping) at 100m depth.
Any help would be appreciated :)


yes indeed @Noil

Could there be humpback whales in the area?

@selene Yes. Humpbacks or Southern right whales

I am not an expert on low frequency whale sounds, but the variety and frequency of a few hundred Hz could maybe be humpback whales. Can you add some info about the season and more specifically the location to your question? A quick google search of 'humpback whale song southern indian ocean' gave me this paper that might be useful Murray et al. 2012
